# Consuming token with AddJwtBearer( ) - fails to validate signature

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I've tried for a couple of days to consume a jwt token in my .net core 2.1 web service. The token is rejected with a `SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed.`-exception.

My setup is quite simple:

```
        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                
            .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions => { 
                configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = "http://localhost/";
                configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String("zeey+h0M8mvWSR9HYKlNns+....")),

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost/",

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "efb4f12d020b434c9b531af96263b3fa",
                };
            });
```

Putting the token I receive into https://jwt.io/, the signature is found valid:

[image]

But my web service still refuses to acknowledge the token.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I get the feeling that jwt.io does not work as it used to anymore. Maybe it's a bug, but instead of verifying the signature, it is just generating it. When I manually type in the key field, I can see the encoded token  change. Also `Signature Verified` just remains.

Comment:  You're right! Looks like the key needs to be filled out before pasting the token. Doing it in that order gives me the `Invalid Signature`-text. Maybe my key is just wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide the code where you generate the token? Also can you provide the exact error message and your ConfigureApp method of Startup-Class?

Comment: I'm not generating the token. I receive the token and tries to consume it.

Comment: Okay can you please still provide the exact error message and show as the ConfigureApp method of Startup-Class?

Comment: @Vegar I justed tested your theory and it works if you paste the key first. So your key must be invalid.

Comment: Hard to tell what’s going on when you hide the useful information about the token, and also don’t show the full error message. The IDX10503 error should show you the attempted keys and will also include exception information. So you should look at that.

Comment: I cannot see how the claims has anything todo with the signature. And the full exception doesn't show anything more - except for the token: `IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: '.`

Comment: Anyway - I've come so far that I know my key is wrong, but I havn't found out why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem:

1. My key was wrong. But even with the correct key, I still got the same error...
2. When constructing the `SymmetricSecurityKey`, I had to use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(...)` instead of `Encoding.ASCII` or `Encoding.UTF8`.
3. I'm still having trouble with jwt.io. I guess this site is no longer a good place for validating tokens.